# factory_girl for ruby is returning an argument error -- why?

Tags: ruby, rspec

my class is defined as:

```
class ScheduleKaya < OrchestrateIo
  def initialize(bot_client_id)
    @bot_client_id = bot_client_id
    @collection = :schedules
    @client = Orchestrate::Client.new(ENV['ORCHESTRATE_API'])
  end
end
```

Factory as:

```
## spec/factories/schedules.rb

FactoryGirl.define do 

    factory :base_schedule, class: ScheduleKaya do 

        bot_client_id "test-client-id"

    end

end
```

Rspec as:

```
context "when creating a new reminder for test-client-id on Feburary 1st 2015" do

      let(:schedule) { FactoryGirl.build(:base_schedule)}
      Timecop.freeze(Chronic.parse("february 14, 2014 at 10am")) 

      it "creates an instance of ScheduleKaya" do

        expect(schedule).to be_a ScheduleKaya

      end
```

And I get an argument error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:schedule) { FactoryGirl.build(:base_schedule)}
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

**Question:** Why is argument wrong, since in the class, it just takes one argument to initialize, and I provide the one in the factory.

Comment: The argument error could be occurring anywhere during the execution of that top level `let` block (e.g. in the middle of `Orchestrate::Client.new`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your factory this way:

```
## spec/factories/schedules.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :base_schedule, class: 'ScheduleKaya' do
    bot_client_id "test-client-id"
  end
end
```

Putting the `class` name inside quotation. See if that fixes your issue.